# Create list of lists from two lists of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists of lists like this:

```
[[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]
[[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]
```

How do I , out of this, create a list of lists:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5], ['cat', 'whale', 'rabbit','dog','zebra','chicken'], [15,10,9,14,22,11]]
```

**Edit**
Just to clarify, what output I need - list of lists sorted by first list.

Comment: What have you already tried? What does not work? The data looks like a list of entries of `Foo(id, name, another_integer_field)`. All you need is to collect the data to a list of `Foo`s, order by `id` and then transform into a single list. However, the approach may also depend on the data size.

Comment: I've done it..but it conforms to this particular question only..i mean it's not generalized

Comment: @GriMel does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how. Works exactly how you want. The logic is that in the first iteration, items are picked up from 'l1' and then `l2`. In the other two, it's `l2` followed by `l1`:

```
l1=[[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]
l2=[[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]
l3=[[],[],[]]
for i in range (3):
    for j in range(3):
        if(j==0):
            l3[i].append(l1[i][j])
            l3[i].append(l2[i][j])
        else:
            l3[i].append(l2[i][j])
            l3[i].append(l1[i][j])
print(l3)
```

Output: `[[0,1,2,3,4,5], ['cat', 'whale', 'rabbit','dog','zebra','chicken'], [15,10,9,14,22,11]]`
Code in action: http://ideone.com/jIlAeK

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
In [30]: l1 = [[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]

In [31]: l2 = [[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]

In [32]: from operator import itemgetter

In [33]: import itertools

In [37]: list(zip(*sorted(itertools.chain(zip(*l1), zip(*l2)), key=itemgetter(0))))
Out[37]: 
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 ('cat', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'zebra', 'chicken'),
 (15, 10, 9, 14, 22, 11)]

In [39]: list(map(list, zip(*sorted(itertools.chain(zip(*l1), zip(*l2)), key=itemgetter(0)))))

Out[39]: 
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 ['cat', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'zebra', 'chicken'],
 [15, 10, 9, 14, 22, 11]]
```

Explanations:

1. `zip(*l)` collects your list into a list of tuples. Each tuple contains three elements: `(id, name, some_integer_field)`. Example:

   ```
   In [35]: list(itertools.chain(zip(*l1), zip(*l2)))
   Out[35]: 
   [(0, 'cat', 15),
    (3, 'dog', 14),
    (5, 'chicken', 11),
    (1, 'whale', 10),
    (2, 'rabbit', 9),
    (4, 'zebra', 22)]
   ```
2. The tuples should be sorted by the first element - this is the reason for `sorted(..., key=operator.itemgetter(0))`
3. Then it should be collected to the single list. Another call to `zip`.
4. Unfortunately, `zip` returns a list of tuples. When you need a list of lists, you should wrap the result of `zip` with call to `map(list, ...)`

Comment: @ShreyansSheth Since when two lines are too long and complex ?

Comment: It's complicated because it's not clear on first look. Plus imports, and too many system functions. Why obfuscate it unnecessarily?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth, Just had no time to add explanations. Fixed now

Comment: This is what i love/hate about stack overflow. Your code for this problem is like Google hiring software engineers for the post of a janitor. Atleast to a relatively new Python user like me :P But I learnt something from this code from the explanation so thanks

Comment: @ShreyansSheth, well, most of all of the code belongs to functional paradigm, rather than Python. The life becomes much easier when you know higher order functions. Glad to help you in learning.

Comment: Aaah that's why. As you can see, my code reflects purely static languages. Totally off the track, but what's a great functional language to start with?

Comment: @ShreyansSheth, well, not sure. I started with Haskell, however, it was pretty unusual. Then I learned how to use FP with C# Linq. Probably, the approach with C# was the best. You may also find useful learning the math aspect of FP, for example the Category theory.

Comment: Coming from a JAVA background,i think presently Scala fits the bill for me. How do you find it compared to Haskell? I saw Scala mentioned in your profile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97649/discussion-between-soon-and-shreyans-sheth).

Answer (score 0):

With list compression you just need 1 line of code

aa=[[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]

bb=[[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]

new_list =  [a+b for a, b in zip(aa, bb)]

print new_list

[[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4], ['cat', 'dog', 'chicken', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [15, 14, 11, 10, 9, 22]]

Answer (score 0):

Using the first entry in the lists as the sort indexes, the following script will give you your expected output:

```
list_1 = [[0, 3, 5], ['cat','dog','chicken'], [15, 14, 11]]
list_2 = [[1, 2, 4], ['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10, 9, 22]]

sort_order = list_1[0] + list_2[0]
output = []

for i1, i2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    source = i1 + i2
    entry = [None] * len(source)

    for i, v in enumerate(source):
        entry[sort_order[i]] = v

    output.append(entry)

print output
```

This will display the following:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['cat', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'dog', 'zebra', 'chicken'], [15, 10, 9, 14, 22, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only few lines required:

```
>>> a = [[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]
>>> b = [[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]
>>> the_list = [c+d for c, d, in zip(a,b)]
>>> print the_list
[[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4], ['cat', 'dog', 'chicken', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [15, 14, 11, 10, 9, 22]]
>>> the_list[0].sort()
>>> print the_list
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['cat', 'dog', 'chicken', 'whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [15, 14, 11, 10, 9, 22]]
```

Comment: This is not the answer, because all lists are connected. The system is id=0, name='cat', counts=15.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for an unspecified number of lists in the top-level list. After merging the two input lists, they get sorted based on the first list values:

```
a = [[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]
b = [[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]
combined = list(zip(*a)) + list(zip(*b))  # create tuples with an element from each sublist then merge them
ordered_tuples = sorted(combined)  # or  more explicitly: sorted(combined, key=lambda x: x[0])
output = list(zip(*ordered_tuples))  # this reverses the sorted tuples into lists as requested
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this script, it worked for me

```
list_1 = [[0,3,5],['cat','dog','chicken'], [15,14,11]]
list_2 = [[1,2,4],['whale', 'rabbit', 'zebra'], [10,9,22]]

list_3 = []

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    list_3.append(list_1[i] + list_2[i])

print(list_3)
```

Comment: Outputs `[[0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4] ...` instead of `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ...`

Comment: I presumed the output sorting was not important, before his edit